# Azure AD admin consent dialog shows unverified publisher

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

[image]

At number 5, the publisher domain, it shows 'not verified' instead of my domain name. How could I make it show the domain name properly?

I have already added custom domain names on my azure directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your domain is verified.

Go to Azure Active Directory->Custom domain names->check if your domain is verified->make your custom domain primary.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! . The problem is that it was not set to primary.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. My domain is set a primary but still its not getting reflected in the consent screen